# What is the best way to return a boolean when a negative value exists in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, boolean

I have the following funciton telling us that a `series` has at least one negative value:

```
def has_negative(series):
    v=False
    for i in range(len(series)):
        if series[i]<0:
            v=True
            break
    return v
```

When we use this function on an example we get :

```
y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
z=[1,-2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

print(has_negative(y))
print(has_negative(y))
```

Output:

```
>>> False
>>> True
```

The function seems to work well, although I want to make it shorter, any suggestion from your side will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilise the built-in *any* function as follows:

```
def has_negative(lst):
    return any(e < 0 for e in lst)

print(has_negative([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
print(has_negative([1,-2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

**Output:**

```
False
True
```

**EDIT:**

Did some timing tests based around this and other suggested answers. Whilst this is concise and functionally correct, it doesn't perform well. Keep it simple and use @quamrana's first suggestion - it's much faster

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the list and get the first element, check if it's a negative. With this approach you don't have to iterate over the array:

```
sorted(series)[0] < 0
```

Comment: btw, of course, `sorted()` iterates over `series` for you. In fact it has to check items more than once, so, while short in text, it could end up quite lengthy in time for a longer `series`.

Comment: depends on what we chase: performance or simplicity. The author said they want it shorter. And yes, I know how `sorted` works.

Answer (score 1):

There are several improvements you can make:

```py
def has_negative(series):
    for i in series:
        if i < 0:
            return True
    return False
```

or it can be contracted into one line like this:

```py
print(bool([i for i in z if i<0]))
```

Comment: Your second suggestion outperforms my answer (using *any*) by a factor of ~30% given the list of values in OP's question. With a longer list my answer outperforms yours. That's counter-intuitive because in your code every element of the input list has to be tested and a list has to be constructed. Whereas with my solution the *any* function could (I don't know how it's implemented) break early - i.e., as soon as it observes a negative value. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: What you have done with your call to `any(...)` is to provide a generator. That means, as you say, that when the first item is detected to be `True`, `any` can just stop calling the generator and return `True`. Maybe the generator takes longer to create than iterating over a short list. IDK. (As soon as I saw that you'd used `any()` I upvoted you)

Answer (score 1):

To add:

To keep it clean and short, you could also use a list comprehension within a lambda function as follows:

```
has_negative = lambda series: True if [series for x in series if x < 0] else False
```

```
z = [1,-2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

has_negative(z)
```

Output:

```
>>> True
```